# Sql Query: 2 tables but looking for all information from one and only one row from the other

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

- Photos: stores all photo information
- Gallery: stores heading and description about the gallery

  ---

I need to echo to a new page the Gallery Description, then all the photos that should be there.

but I keep getting heading and description repeating because its in the same

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)...
```

then there is more that one set of photos in that gallery I need also?

anyone help or am I being to vague....

```
$a="SELECT * from gallery where gallery_category=".$gallery_category;
$result = mysql_query($a,$c);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['gallery_name'].'<br>'.$row['gallery_description'].'<br>';
    $sql="SELECT * FROM photos WHERE gallery_id =".$gallery_id." ORDER BY photos_filename";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql,$c);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo'<a rel="example_group" href="../galleries/images/'.$row['gallery_id'].'/'.$row['photos_filename'].'" width="130" height="100"><img src="../galleries/images/'.$row['gallery_id'].'/'.$row['photos_filename'].'" height="150px" alt=""/></a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you post more of your Code

Comment: being abit vague but you have 2 solutions. either loop once through your galleries table and then in each itteration of the while pull and loop your photos where the photo galleryid matches the id of the gallery or you can use a join to pull it all at once and in code store the gallery ID and only echo out the gallery header if the current gallery id stored doesn't match the gallery id from the db

Comment: You are trying to get info about gallery and it's photos in a single query or what? Please, provide some code and examples of current output.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM photos` : If you want to query two tables then you should use the two tables. In your case, both query refer to the same table, `photos`. Table `Gallery` never used.

Comment: **Next hint** 1) replace your first query `SELECT * FROM photos ...` with `SELECT * FROM gallery ...` your code will work. 2) To get not ultra long lines, you should end up with some "<br>\n" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I'll post it up here so I can use some code formatting.

**Option 1 - loop within a loop**

```
$headerquery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl1");
while ($headers= $db->fetchNextObject($headerquery )) {
   echo "<table><tr><th>".$headers->GalleryName."</th></tr>"; // open table create header
       $detailquery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE GalleryID=".$headers->ID);
       while ($details= $db->fetchNextObject($detailquery )) {
          echo "<tr><td>".$details->Photo."</td></tr>"; //loop through 2nd table and spit out photos
       }
   echo "</table>"; //close table
}
```

**Option 2 - joined query with selector**

```
$galleryheaderid = 0;
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.ID=tbl2.GalleryID");
while ($details = $db->fetchNextObject($query )) {
   echo "<table>";
   if ($galleryheaderid!=$details->ID) { //spit out header row if id's don't match
       echo "<tr><th>".$details ->GalleryName."</th></tr>"; //create header
       $galleryheaderid = $details->ID;  //set header id to gallery id so we don't show header a 2nd time
   } 
   echo "<tr><td>".$details->Photo."</td></tr>"; //spit out gallery information even on first row since all rows include photo information

   echo "</table>"; //close table
}
```

Something like either of these should work obviously they'll need completing properly

Comment: Sorted..... kept it simple and entered a $gallery_id on each loop through... works a treat... thanks for the help..